# Python http.server останавливается

Tags: python, сервер

При запуске скрипта на сервере его выполнение прекращается часов через 10, хотя сам процесс не останавливается

Comment: Не знаю, может, кто-то все понял, но не могли бы дополнить вопрос: как запускаете? как узнаете, что выполнение скрипта прекращается? как поняли, что сам процесс не останавливается?

Comment: Я запуская скрипт на удалённом сервере. Простейший, который просто пишет ссылку, по которой к нему обратились. Запуская через screen вечером. Утром вижу, что сам скрипт не прекращает работу (не вылетает), но на запросы он не отвечает

Comment: Попробуйте добавить логирование в скрипт. Вероятно на чем то зависает. Лимит соединений и они не закрываются, занятый порт и тд.. Без примера кода это гадание на кофейной гуще.